# SalesForce How to Join Works?

Tags: soql, inner-join

My SQL Query for Join

```
SELECT LoginIp.SourceIp, LoginHistory.SourceIp 
FROM ( LoginHistory INNER JOIN LoginIp ON LoginHistory.SourceIp = LoginIp.SourceIp)
```

To get `Source Ip` from `LoginIp` table and `Login History` table get using inner join.
how can i do this in Sales force . I am using 40.0 **partner** wsdl sales force service reference .

I need exact query for do this operation.
I am also tried this query also

```
SELECT LoginIp.SourceIp,( Select  LoginHistory.SourceIp  from LoginHistory)  from LoginIp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a distinction in Salesforce between simple data vales (such as string fields like `SourceIp`) and object relationships: you can only do joins across the latter. Worth studying e.g [A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com) for a while to see what is and isn't possible.

From quick check of the data model, the `LoginHistory` and `LoginIp` objets do not have a direct relationship, though they are both related to `User`. You may have to do two queries to grab the fields you want.